# How to backup a user profile and restore it in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, user-profiles

I want to install a fresh copy of Windows 7, and remove the old one.

How can I backup and restore my user accounts to the new installation to be as the old ones??

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Windows Start Menu Search and type “**backup and restore**“. Select the first search result which will be Windows Backup and Restore utility.
- Select the destination where you would like to back up your user profile. You can either choose a drive in your computer or a network share. There is no option to select a specific folder to back up to.
- Once you have selected the drive, it will create a folder called Backup and back up all your data in the Backup folder.
  On the next screen, you should choose “**Let me choose**” radio button to select the profile to back up.

[image: Screen]

More details:

- http://www.maketecheasier.com/3-ways-to-backup-user-profile-in-windows-7/2011/06/11
- [Windows 7 Backup and Restore](http://kb.ucla.edu/articles/windows-7-backup-and-restore)

Answer (score 2):

Run the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer)  to transfer all user settings and personal data.

> When you're switching to a new PC, Windows Easy Transfer helps you
>   transfer your files, email, pictures, and settings. In Windows 7, it
>   lives up to the "easy" in its name.
>
> You told us previous versions of Windows Easy Transfer were hard to
>   figure out or stalled before the job was done. So we redesigned it to
>   be more reliable and more helpful. It now includes a file explorer so
>   you can easily choose exactly which files to copy to your new PC. And
>   if Windows finds a file or setting it can't work with, your transfer
>   won't hang up—it will finish and give you a full report of anything
>   that didn't migrate.

[image]

Comment: It states it works from XP to Windows 7, though, will it work from windows 7 to windows 7?

Comment: @ZJR yes it works fine.