# Mistake after deleting AppData folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I unfortunately deleted AppData and ProgramData folder from C drive since because I wanted to gain space. This resulted in deleting of all apps from my Windows 7 tiles. Also my Store App is also not responding to reinstall apps.

Is there a way to reset my PC to the original state?

Comment: Um, ouch? AppData and ProgramData should not EVER be touched by anyone directly unless they absolutely know what they're doing. Now, what brand and model computer do you have? We'll need to know this in order to specify how you can do a system restore.

Comment: I tried to use system restore but it didn't work because i didn't creat one before. I'm using Dell XPS - 15z. Please help me. This will be a preciouse exp for me. Thanks so much @music2myear

Comment: By the way, if I use Easus todo to recover the folder, will it work?

Comment: Eh, I fell for the javaw.exe teddy-bear icon virus hoax years ago, now I'm an IT professional. So, I can't really in good conscience prescribe you an Etch-A-Sketch without requiring one for myself too. Please see the answer I'll post below in a minute.

Comment: There are data recovery programs out there, but data recovery isn't necessarily for recovering data necessary for returning your system to a working state, but to recover personal data such as documents and pictures. There are parts of the files that are supposed to change in an orderly and predictable manner, and simply recovering the folders and pasting them back into place is more likely to leave you with a crippled system. Better to do a full system restore.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN117599:

First: **BACK UP YOUR DATA**

Next:

1. Turn on the computer.
2. As the computer starts, press < F8 > on the keyboard until the Advanced Boot Options menu appears on the screen. *You must press before the Windows logo appears on the screen. If you press after the Windows logo appears on the screen, the Advanced Boot Options menu will not appear on the screen. If you do not see the Advanced Boot Options menu, restart the computer, and then repeat this step until you see the menu on the screen.*
3. Press the < Down Arrow > on the keyboard to select Repair Your Computer on the Advanced Boot Options menu, and then press < Enter >.
4. Specify the language settings that you want, and then click Next.
5. Log in as a user who has administrative credentials, and then click OK.
6. Click Dell Factory Image Restore.
7. In the Dell Factory Image Restore window, click Next.
8. Click to select the Yes, reformat hard drive and restore system software to factory condition check box.
9. Click Next. The computer is restored to the default factory configuration.
10. When the restore operation is completed, click Finish to restart the computer. The software is now installed as it was when the computer was first received.

Comment: If I do that mean all the softwares I installed before went out, right? Sorry because I'm not good at English to describe fully what I want to u. I mean, I want everything works properly, included my installed software. Some of them work normally, some doesn't like the default software of Windows like Paint or Calculator etc..I really don't want to lose my softwares

Comment: Both AppData and ProgramData contain much more than simply your Windows 7 tiles. They contain critical program and operating system data. Deleting them has likely done irrecoverable damage to your system, though the extent of it might not be immediately apparent. A skilled technician taking your entire computer may be able to piece together the software the way it needs to be for correct functioning, but for an average user, the correct and best method of fixing this is to restore your computer to its original state and reinstall all applications.

Comment: I see now.Thanks for your very useful advice. And can u show me how to back up all my data, please (:

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/590676/how-to-backup-a-user-profile-and-restore-it-in-windows-7

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm really really appreciate what u did to help me. If u have a chance to visit Vietnam, my country, just contact me and I'll take u around the city for sure ;)

Comment: I believe Vietnam is on my list of places to visit. I haven't been to anywhere in Asia yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's an interesting country for visiting. And how can we share our contacts in private way? I can't find how to send a msg for u in this site.