# Move specific Windows-10 user profile and installed software to a new pc

Tags: windows-10, clone, profile

It's along the lines of this question but what is not clear if this process will move also my installed programs/games/software that I want to move along to a new computer that is already setup.

Here is the original question I was trying to do research on before trying it out. 
https://superuser.com/a/1344935/1024403

Here is the situation in summary,
I setup a new PC and setup couple of profiles there for the family, spent a lot of time getting every thing just right.
Now I have a laptop that I have a local user account on where I set it up for my gaming and installed software related to games.
What I want to be able to do is to move that profile from the laptop to the new Windows-10 pc 'as is'. I thought some thing like Acronys might let me do it but not possible.
Is it possible and if yes then how to move my profile and installed software from one Windows-10 laptop to another Windows-10 PC that have other profiles running and I don't want to change them (just add a new profile as is). Please note the profile in the original laptop is a local profile and not linked to a microsoft account.

Comment: You can move the data within the profile directory but the user itself cannot be moved nor can the applications.  So in other word your configuration changes cannot be transferred to another PC.  You would have to clone the HDD from the first machine but that would present activation and Windows licensing issues that you might not want to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

You may transfer user profiles on Windows 10, but you cannot transfer installed
products - you will need to reinstall them or do some detective work on where
the product is installed on disk and in the registry.

The tool to use for transferring profiles is Windows Easy Transfer.
Although not available for Windows versions later than 7, it can be transferred
by copying from Windows 7 or downloading the folder
[from here](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/migwiz.zip).

With this tool you may transfer user accounts, documents, videos, music, pictures
and email and browser favorites for Microsoft products.

For details about using the tool, see for example the article
[Transfer Files from Windows XP, Vista, 7 or 8 to Windows 10 using Windows Easy Transfer](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-10/transfer-files-from-windows-xp-vista-7-8-to-windows-10-using-windows-easy-transfer/).

Comment: Thanks let me try it out but my challenge was installed programs unfortunately