# Moving programs from Windows 7 laptop (Dell XPS) to Win 10 laptop (Lenovo IdeaPad L340)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I am trying to move certain programs from an older Win 7 to a new Win 10 laptop without doing a re-install. Is there a way to make a mirror image of pre-selected items on a drive, or can this only be done on the entire drive? Both laptops have SSDs.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://superuser.com/questions/1427741/move-specific-windows-10-user-profile-and-installed-software-to-a-new-pc. Unfortunately it doesn't have an upvoted answer, so cannot be flagged as such.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Windows 10 OS is running (preinstalled likely), no, you cannot do this. You must reinstall the programs. Also use updated versions to help ensure compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools exist to migrate applications from Windows 7 to Windows 10, such as https://www.easeus.com/pc-transfer/free-pc-mover-for-windows8-7.html . Here's a review article which covers more migration apps: https://www.maketecheasier.com/transfer-programs-from-one-pc-to-another/

However, it takes extremely deep knowledge of an app to successfully migrate it, and if the tool make does not have that knowledge, migration will fail.  Apps install not only into [%SYSTEMDRIVE%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)\Program Files\ but also into %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\$USERNAME\AppData , into the Registry (which is assembled at boot from [multiple Windows system files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry)), and quite possibly into Alternate Data Streams at the discretion of the publisher who created the program. Each application can use different files and Registry entries.

Windows also surveys the hardware environment to create a unique and largely undocumented 'fingerprint' of a PC, to prevent Windows from being moved from one PC to another without buying a new license. Changing something small, such as a video card or a drive will not trigger Windows to demand re-registration with a new license, but multiple items will.

In short, making an image of computer *X* and trying to run it on computer *Y* is rarely effective. This only works reliably for corporate licensed Windows installations where the IT Department has License Servers, and IT Department issues are [off-topic here on SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I never had success with any such product.