# Copy back previous user and program folders after Windows reinstallation?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-installation, user-profiles, reinstall

Has anyone ever tried, after a fresh Windows installation, to simply restore the previous user (C:\Users) and programs folders (C:\Program Files (x86), C:\Program Files) from the previous installation, in order to restore as many settings and programs as possible without having to reinstall and re-setup everything from scratch?

Since the user-specific part of the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER = NTUSER.DAT) is stored in the user folder, this should get one pretty far?

Or is [this](https://administrator.de/contentid/400462#comment-1342828) a better way:

1. Install Windows fresh from scratch
2. Create and log in with a new user account
3. Log off user and log in as administrator
4. Reboot computer
5. Log in as admin (i.e. not as old user and not as new user)
6. Open Explorer
7. Right click "This PC" -> Properties ->  Advanced System Properties -> User Profiles
8. Copy the old user profile into the new one using "Copy" and enter the new user as owner.

"Only this way all settings (incl. Registry) are taken over and also the permissions are set correctly."

I would love to use the latter method of importing the previous user profile into the fresh Windows installation, but when I try to do so, using a copy of the previous user's User Folder, the previous username does not show up in the advanced system settings/account transfer:

[image]

...so I can't copy it over to the new user.

Thus, how is it possible to import a user profile (including HKEY_CURRENT_USER = NTUSER.DAT) from the previous Windows installation into a fresh Windows installation?

Comment: I suspect you will have issues with the user GUID being different even if it is the same user name.

Comment: Ok thanks. If this should be the case, I suppose it should be possible to edit all occurrences of the user GUID in NTUSER.DAT before copying it back.

Comment: Yeah, you might have to fiddle with file ownership as well

Comment: What about the other way I just found (I put in the question for better formatting)

Comment: No; if you want an existing user I would stop performing a clean install, and just upgrade the existing installation

Comment: Thanks -- however, I'm specifically looking for a way to do that transfer with a fresh installation.

Comment: I would love to use the second method of importing the previous user profile into the fresh Windows installation, but it doesn't work yet. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I've found the fantastic free tool [ForensiT Transwiz](http://www.forensit.com/move-computer.html) which makes this undertaking as easy as pie with just a few clicks!

(The part of copying back the entire previous User folder, including HKCU=NTUSER.DAT)

[image: ForensiT Transwiz]