# How to carefully-and-selectively backup a Windows 10 profile, not using the built-in facilities

Tags: windows-10, backup, automation, user-profiles

Here's how you can backup your Windows profile:

[How to backup a local Windows 10 user profile and restore it in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1344893/how-to-backup-a-local-windows-10-user-profile-and-restore-it-in-windows-10)

... except that doesn't work for me:

1. That backs up *everything* and the kitchen sink. I don't want that. I want to be much more frugal (e.g. presented checkbox-based options for consideration, or some other way).
2. I want to make sure I don't backup junk I don't need, e.g. temporary and cache files, and other files which will just get auto-generated and do not reflect any choices I've explicitly made or input I've provided. Naturally, if the sizes of such items of junk these are small, then I don't mind the backup much, but these things have a tendency to add up.
3. The machine on which the backup is performed doesn't have an extra drive; and for reasons, I can't connect an external drive to it. I need the backup to result in a file (e.g. an archive file).
4. When I restore, I want to avoid the restoration messing up my profile in case I perform it on an installation on a different physical machine, and possibly with a later Windows edition.

How can I effect a backup, under these constraints? An answer can be either a list of things to do/copy, which I could filter; or a procedure involving tools which would let me exercise such fine-grained control.

Comment: "Carefully and selectively" are opposing goals. My experience with backing up only partial data has been that is is *useless*. When something goes wrong, vital data is almost invariably missing from a partial backup. Yes a full drive image *does* take up about as much space as is used on the drive, *but it works*. That said, you *can* back up, separately, some things such as a Firefox or Thunderbird profile, and even copy them to another PC. But this will not capture the Registry settings, for example, broken into multiple files.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I understand that selective backup has its dangers, but - that's what I want to do. I have a huge user profile file dir I'm looking at, and a whole lot of it really doesn't need to be backed up at all.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but what you want can't be done natively and software recommendations are off-topic here.  You have some *very* specific requirements that are rather unusual, but I can pass along what I do on my own home network (Windows 10 Pro machines) that works quite well. Once a month, I use external media to manually backup the following folders: Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Music, Pictures, and Videos. Everything else has a cloud-based backup, such as Firefox bookmarks. Altogether, this is effective whenever I need to reload Windows, move to new computer, etc.

Comment: @Run5k: The selection of "obviously" backup-relevant individual folders from under Users\MyUsername is pretty straightforward. The part I would need help with is basically "everything else", e.g.: is exporting HKCU from the registry enough to capture what's related to my user? And how to properly sift through the chaffe in AppData, generally and for some commonly-used apps. But - I guess I might need to look for a profile backup tool.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to have *that* level of fidelity, then yes, a profile backup tool would probably be ideal.  Personally, I have been managing Windows-based client operating systems for more than two decades, and I have never found a compelling reason to salvage anything from HKCU or the AppData folder.  When we help our end users migrate to a new machine, we find that it is preferable to help them with a fresh start.   There are too many variables for us to do that much of a deep dive into profile configurations.  But I'm sure that you could easily find good software reviews online.

Comment: @Run5k: Thanks. My experience is backing up Linux user profiles, not so much Windows. I guess if I were more experienced I'd know what to expect I would need.