# Copy user profile (credentials) from one windows machine to another

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, backup, user-profiles

After some googling:

[How to backup a user profile and restore it in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/590676/how-to-backup-a-user-profile-and-restore-it-in-windows-7)

[How to backup a local Windows 10 user profile and restore it in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1344893/how-to-backup-a-local-windows-10-user-profile-and-restore-it-in-windows-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/copying-user-profile-or-cloning-a-user-account/06aac64f-d1d8-4eb9-bea2-7a55a1a6b04f

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-your-data

I'm still not sure if:

- how can a profile be exported with its credentials only (and not the binaries/settings installed under 
  that profile)?
- when the profile is imported, is it imported "over" an existing profile or alongside of existing 
  profiles on the new machine?

To give some context, I need to setup a VPN connection; setup is successful, but connecting from other profiles aside from the ones whitelisted does not allow for accessing network drives, even if the VPN connection is successful.

I'm guessing that creating a user with the same username/credentials as a whitelisted profile wouldn't or rather shouldn't work (since profiles should be unique).

Answer (score 0):

> How can a profile be exported with its credentials only (and not the binaries/settings installed under that profile)?

Windows does not support exporting or importing of a user profile.  Even if you were to create the same username on two machines, they would be unique users, and would only be able to authenticate on the machine they exist on.

> When the profile is imported, is it imported "over" an existing profile or alongside of existing profiles on the new machine?

You can only migrate the contents of a profile directory to another user profile, but that is just copying files, and does not involve exporting or importing a user.